# django print variable in template from class based view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

In the following code i am trying to  print `display_name` in the template. But i see that it is empty .What am i doing wrong here ?

Views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      display_name = "Test123"
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('site:index'),{'display_name': display_name})
```

In template

```
 {{display_name}} //Its empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are re-directing. While you are adding `display_name` to the context for this request, firing `HttpResponseRedirect` means you are making a new request which isn't aware of the context you have created.  Instead, you should add `display_name` to the view you are redirecting to. possibly using a session variable if you need to pass the `display_name` to the next page.

Edit: in response to your question
You should add `display_name` to the session (all code is untested):

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session['display_name'] = 'Test123'
        self.request.session.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('site:index'))
```

Then in the target page you'd use the `get_content_data` method described by cor:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'display_name' in self.request.session:
            context['display_name'] = self.request.session['display_name']
            del(self.request.session['display_name'])

        return context
```

Comment: self.request.session['display_name'] = 'Test123' and   self.request.session.save() how to print request variable for display_name in template. {{request.GET.display_name}} ????

Comment: It's there in the get_context_data method. Because you are adding `display_name` as an element in the `context` dictionary, you just need to use `{{ display_name }}` in the template

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "yourtemplate.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["display_name"] = "Test123"
        return context
```

Comment: While this is the correct method for class based views, the reason it isn't working for Rajeev is that he is redirecting after setting the context, so his variable isn't available to the page which gets loaded.

Comment: But how to do it with httpresponse redirect() ?

Comment: Try my code, and append your get function, without the "display_name" variable

Comment: cor the problem is that the html page that is called is unknown , so i decided to go by httpresponse redirect.Is there a way to go by my solution